# Fill nulls in Python Polars lazyframe by groups, conditional on the number of unique values in each group

Tags: python, window-functions, large-data, python-polars, unique-values

I have a large (~300M rows x 44 cols) dataframe and I need to fill in null values in certain ways depending on the characteristics of each group.

For example, say we have

```
lf = pl.LazyFrame(
    {'group':(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
     'val':('yes', None, 'no', '2', '2', '2', 'answer', None, 'answer')
     }
)
```

```
┌───────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ val    │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64   ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ 1     ┆ yes    │
│ 1     ┆ null   │
│ 1     ┆ no     │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
│ 3     ┆ null   │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
└───────┴────────┘
```

I want to fill in nulls if and only if the group contains a single non-null unique value in the other cells, since in my context that's the expectation of the data and the presense of more than one unique value (or all nulls) in the group signals another issue that will be handled differently.

I'm able to fill null values for each group with the following:

```
filled_lf = (
    lf
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('val')
        .fill_null(pl.col('val').unique().first().over('group')).alias('filled_val')
        )
    )
```

However, for one, it seems that pl.col('val').unique() includes 'null' as one of the values, and the ordering is stochastic so choosing the first value on the list has inconsistent results. Secondly, it doesn't include the condition I need.

Desired result:

```
┌───────┬────────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ val    ┆ filled_val │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ i64   ┆ str    ┆ str        │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ yes    ┆ yes        │
│ 1     ┆ null   ┆ null       │
│ 1     ┆ no     ┆ no         │
│ 2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2          │
│ 2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2          │
│ 2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2          │
│ 3     ┆ answer ┆ answer     │
│ 3     ┆ null   ┆ answer     │
│ 3     ┆ answer ┆ answer     │
└───────┴────────┴────────────┘
```

Pandas 3.12
Polars 0.20.1

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

- [`.drop_nulls()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.drop_nulls.html#polars.Expr.drop_nulls)
- [`.unique()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.unique.html#polars.Expr.unique) with `maintain_order=True`
- [`when/then/otherwise`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html) to implement the conditional count/len logic

```py
unique = pl.col("val").drop_nulls().unique(maintain_order=True)

df.with_columns(
   pl.when(unique.len().over("group") == 1)
     .then(pl.col("val").fill_null(unique.first().over("group")))
     .otherwise(pl.col("val"))
     .alias("filled")
)
```

```py
shape: (9, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ val    ┆ filled │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64   ┆ str    ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╪════════╡
│ 1     ┆ yes    ┆ yes    │
│ 1     ┆ null   ┆ null   │
│ 1     ┆ no     ┆ no     │
│ 2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2      │
│ 3     ┆ answer ┆ answer │
│ 3     ┆ null   ┆ answer │
│ 3     ┆ answer ┆ answer │
└───────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: FYI - this is the only method that works for me in a stable manner with my dataset. The other methods mentioned involve a glitch somewhere when applying the window function more than once. For the life of me, I cannot get the glitch to show up with sample data, and only seems to occur with my full dataset, so I imagine the glitch is somewhere in the streaming engine, but I'm not sure. 

I'm using python 3.12, polars 0.20.6.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`drop_nulls()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.drop_nulls.html) and [`n_unique()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.n_unique.html) to calculate amount of unique values within the column. After that, you don't even need to use [`fill_null()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_null.html), cause you know that you want your whole column to have the same value:

```py
lf.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col('val').drop_nulls().n_unique() == 1
    ).then(
        pl.col('val').drop_nulls().first()
    ).otherwise(
        pl.col('val')
    ).over('group')
)

┌───────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ val    │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64   ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ 1     ┆ yes    │
│ 1     ┆ null   │
│ 1     ┆ no     │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
└───────┴────────┘
```

Alternatively, for your case you don't even need to calculate amount of unique values. You only care if there's one unique value within the group, so you can use [`min()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.min.html) and [`max()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.max.html) within the group:

```py
lf.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col('val').min() == pl.col('val').max()
    ).then(
        pl.col('val').max()
        # alternatively you can use
        # pl.col('val').fill_null('max')
    ).otherwise(
        pl.col('val')
    ).over('group')
)

┌───────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ val    │
│ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ i64   ┆ str    │
╞═══════╪════════╡
│ 1     ┆ yes    │
│ 1     ┆ null   │
│ 1     ┆ no     │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 2     ┆ 2      │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
│ 3     ┆ answer │
└───────┴────────┘
```

**update**

as mentioned in the comments, both ways fail on the full dataset. I don't know what exact problem is, but I also see possible logical problem in my code - the `over` expression is applied to the full `when.then.otherwise` expression, while it doesn't have to be applied to `otherwise` part of it. It seems to be working (kudos to polars expression parser) but I see how it might be problematic.
So one suggestion might be to move `over` clause inside of the `when.then.otherwise` expression parts to make parser' life easier:

```py
lf.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col('val').drop_nulls().n_unique().over('group') == 1
    ).then(
        pl.col('val').drop_nulls().first().over('group')
    ).otherwise(
        pl.col('val')
    )
)
```

Comment: FYI - these methods work for all the small/sample data sets I have thrown at them, and as far as I can tell are logically equivalent to the code from @jqurious; however, I'm getting a glitch somewhere when applying the window function more than once. For the life of me, I cannot get the glitch to show up with sample data, and only seems to occur with my full dataset, so I imagine the glitch is somewhere in the streaming engine, but I'm not sure. I'm using python 3.12, polars 0.20.6. Thanks again!

Comment: @epistemetrica For debugging you can see if it succeeds with `.collect(no_optimization=True)` - if this is the case, you can try narrow it down to a particular optimization e.g. `.collect(comm_subexpr_elim=False)` (the CSE optimizer)

Comment: @epistemetrica I've added a small suggestion to the answer.